# How many job offers do Phineas and Ferb have?

Tags: phineas-and-ferb

Occasionally adults have taken note of Phineas and Ferb's talent.  How many times have they offered a job to the duo?  I'd like to also count offers for just one of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I count 4 so far, but I'm sure I'm missing some.

#### Flop Starz

Perhaps not a long term job, but the record company executive tried to sign them up for one more single.

> Well, okay then! We prepared to offer you a very lucrative contract if you'll just sign exclusively with us for your follow-up single.

#### Toy to the World

The toy factory C.E.O. was very interested.

> There you are, Phineas and what's-his-name. Perry the Platypus is a smashing hit! So, what's your next big idea?

He's even tripled their salary earlier.

#### Nerds of a feather

Clive Addison finds their special effects special.

> Well it's just really clear that you two are going to have an amazing career in special effects ahead of you. And if that's what you want, give me a call in ten years and I'll hire the both of you in a heartbeat.

This is the only one that Phineas and Ferb didn't immediately reject.

#### Chez Platypus

Not actually a job offer, but Phineas and Ferb's restaurant is trendy enough that an entrepreneur buys the brand to start a franchise based on it.  Phineas and Ferb agree, but it's not clear if they accept money for this.

#### Ladies and Gentlemen, Meet Max Modem!

Ok, this one is so sketchy it might not count.  Dad becomes an eighties retro pop star in a band with Phineas and Ferb, as “Max Modem and the Mainframes”.  He gets an offer for a tour together with Lindana.  Presumably if he had accepted, he'd have sung with Phineas and Ferb in the band.

#### Phineas and Ferb: Mission Marvel

In the Marvel crossover episode, Iron Man gives an internship to Ferb for next summer.